# Dell XPS 13 9365 with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: dell, xps

I have a Dell XPS 13 9365 with a 256GB Toshiba Nvme Disk.  I can install software and boot up intially but after I logoff and restart, it just hangs and the Dell Splash Screen with the Ubuntu logo going in a circle.  If I restart the system there apears to be 2 startup drives one which is the Nvme drive that I created and the other is the a standard UBUNTU option.  The only way that I can get it to boot is to manually select this everytime.  Rearranging the boot order is no help for me.  Any clues on why it will not boot up automatically?

Comment: It would be helpful if you can add some screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

I work in IT in a company, and we have several 9570's, 7590's and 9370s in use. One thing we have to do across all the ubuntu installations is to enable the `nomodeset` flag in the grub configuration. Dell has described how in here: https://www.dell.com/support/article/en-us/sln306327/manual-nomodeset-kernel-boot-line-option-for-linux-booting?lang=en

It's worth a shot during boot to edit the grub config manually first, before entering it into the file itself.